# Differentiate Button Colors using event.target.classlist

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events

I just generated the dynamic buttons with colors. Have to differentiate that last clicked buttons and visited buttons by using different colors with `event.target.classlist`

```js
var buttonId = 0;
var classId = 0;

function myFunction()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "F093F5";
        btn.setAttribute("id", "btn" + buttonId);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "class" + classId);
       
        btn.addEventListener('click', keyFunction);
        btn.innerText = "click" + buttonId;
        btn.innerText = "click" + classId;
        console.log(btn);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);

        buttonId++;
        classId++;

    }
}
{
    function keyFunction(event)
    {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor="#D3D578";
        var elem = event.target.classlist;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="cl" id="1" onclick="myFunction()" onkeypress="keyFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: It's `event.target.classList`, not `event.target.classlist`! Javascript is case-sensitive!

Comment: Ok... But what kind of logic for that ..

Comment: The property is called `classList`, with a *big L*. That's the logic. And by the way, I don't understand what you want to achieve with this line of code.

Comment: ok i'lI change that.. I just asking logic for how to diffrentiate last clicked and visited buttons. I didn't achieve anything with this.. Asking how to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This is a first attempt to color the buttons differently, depending on the id. But I'm still not sure what's the purpose of this script.

```js
var buttonId = 0;
var classId = 0;

function myFunction() {

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "F093F5";
        btn.setAttribute("id", "btn" + buttonId);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "class" + classId);
       
        btn.addEventListener('click', keyFunction);
        btn.innerText = "click" + buttonId;
        btn.innerText = "click" + classId;
        console.log(btn);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);

        buttonId++;
        classId++;
    }
}

var colors = ["#ea4747", "#eaa947", "#c9ea47", "#68ea47", "#47ea88", "#47eaea", "#4788ea", "#6847ea", "#c947ea", "#ea47a9"];

function keyFunction(event) {
    var id = event.target.id.replace("btn", "") * 1;
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[id % 10];
}
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<button class="cl" id="1" onclick="myFunction()" onkeypress="keyFunction()">Try it</button><br>
```

**EDIT**:

This is the CSS for a button that has different colors on different button states:

```css
button {
  border: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: .1s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #77ccf7;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #ff7733;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello!</button><button>Hello!</button>
```

Comment: Purpose?..Dude it's a task for me

Comment: So is does the script what you want?

Comment: All visited buttons colors would be same.. And other color for active button

Comment: You do that with CSS: Use the selectors `button`, `button:hover`, `button:focus` and `button:active` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes